# How do channels and rank interact if using pair-matched RDIMMs?

Tags: memory, ecc

So, my Supermicro X10 R3 board has a single CPU with 8 DDR4 DIMM slots. When fully loaded it has 2 DIMM pairs in each channel x 4 channels (I think). I always use only matched pairs of DIMMs. The current CPU is an E5-1650 v4.

My available RDIMMs are all standardised on 16gb at the moment. I have some pairs of 2Rx4 16gb DIMMs, and some pairs of 1Rx4 16gb DIMMs. I could also get hold of 1Rx8 and 2Rx8 16gb pairs. Otherwise they are identical spec (all 2400 17 cas, etc).

Assuming each of the 4 pairs of DIMMs comprises 2 matched DIMMs of the same type:

- What are the implications for performance/speed, stability, and ECC functionality, if the matched pairs are all 1R, all 2R, or some channels have 2 x (1Rx4) DIMMs while other channels have 2 x (2Rx4) DIMMs?
- Am I right that chip width by itself doesn't make any difference provided both DIMMs in a channel are matched and otherwise identical?  (Meaning, matched pairs all with identical spec except that some channels have 2 x (2Rx4) 16gb 2400 cas17 and others have 2 x (2Rx8) 16gb 2400 cas17?)
- Would the answer be the same regardless of baseboard brand?

*(Note: I've looked at other questions on mixing 1R+2R but they cover mixing in general, rather than mixing but keeping each channel matched, and none seem to explicitly discuss  the interaction between matched channel pairing + rank which is what I'm trying to understand. Some sources seem to say mixing is **safe**, others that RAM will work but **ECC detect/correct won't necessarily work as fully as it should** if the ranks are mixed, others that they **shouldn't** be mixed)*